# get HTML and generate an IMAGE in canvas with rasterizehtml - dynamic source image

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I try to generate multi layered HTML content to canvas/ image

1. bottom layer an **image**
2. top layer other content

Here is my JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/rako87/b3qhLm5u/7/

My issue is, when I change the bottom layer image source its not reflecting on the rendered canvas (always render the original HTML value)

How could I achieve that when I change the img src with JS that is reflecting on the rendered IMG ??

THX!

JS:

```
// IMG dropdown select
var selectBox = document.getElementById('selectBox');
var theImg = document.getElementById('theImg');

selectBox.addEventListener('change', function() {
  theImg.src = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value
}, false);

// Generate IMG to canvas with button click
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
  context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  html_container = document.getElementById("thehtml"),
  html = html_container.innerHTML;

$(function() { 
        $("#btnGEN").click(function() { 
            rasterizeHTML.drawHTML(html).then(function (renderResult) {
                context.drawImage(renderResult.image, 0, 0);
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Why? Doesn't https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ do exactly what you want?

Comment: And to answer your question, there may be a few ways to do what you want... consider creating a "new context", then redraw everything onto that new context - if I understand the problem. Which would mean that you'd move your `var canvas = ..., context = ..., html_container = ..., html = ...` inside of your jquery `.click` event listener.

Comment: Odd enough `rasterizeHTML` is not defined in your script, works in jfiddle, but when I try to add a runnable code snippet in S.O., it says it isn't defined.

Comment: I add rasterizehtml.js under “Resources” in jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's up with the code snippet below (the error: `rasterizeHTML.allinone.js:11 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of null`), but when I use the javascript portion of the code in your jsfiddle, I think it accomplishes what you were wanting.

```js
// IMG dropdown select
var selectBox = document.getElementById('selectBox');
var theImg = document.getElementById('theImg');

selectBox.addEventListener('change', function() {
  theImg.src = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value
}, false);


$(function() {
        $("#btnGEN").click(function() {
          // Generate IMG to canvas with button click
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
            context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
            html_container = document.getElementById("thehtml"),
            html = html_container.innerHTML;
            rasterizeHTML.drawHTML(html).then(function (renderResult) {
                context.drawImage(renderResult.image, 0, 0);
            });
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rasterizehtml/1.3.0/rasterizeHTML.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rasterizehtml/1.3.0/rasterizeHTML.allinone.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th width="300px">HTML</th>
    <th width="300px">Rendered IMG</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    
    <p>1.Select source img: </p>
    <select id="selectBox">
        <option value="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/1d83b3/ffffff.jpg&text=+">Blue</option>
        <option value="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/1f995a/ffffff.jpg&text=+">Green</option>
    </select>   <br/><br/>
    
    <p>2.Click Button to Generate img to canvas: </p>
    <button type="button" id="btnGEN" >Generate</button><br/>

    <br/>
    

   <div id="thehtml" style="position:relative;">
      <style>
          .test {
            font-size: 22px;    
          }
      </style>
    
   
      <div style="z-index:0; position:absolute;">
        <img id="theImg" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/1d83b3/ffffff.jpg&text=+">
      </div>
      
      <div style="z-index:1; position:absolute;">
        <h2> TEST TEXT </h2>
      </div>
      
    </div>

  
    </td>
    <td><canvas id="canvas" width="220" height="220" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```